# Fancybox - how can I show thumbnails by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

How can I show these thumbnails by default?
[image]

Live code example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dahos18j/4/) 
I am using Fancybox api for open lightbox by click.

```
        $.fancybox.defaults.buttons = ["zoom", "thumbs", "close" ];

        $('.fancybox-btn').click(function () {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    src  : 'http://placehold.it/300x200?text=1',
                    opts : {
                        thumb   : 'http://placehold.it/300x200?text=1'
                    }
                },
                {
                    src  : 'http://placehold.it/300x200?text=2',
                    opts : {
                        thumb   : 'http://placehold.it/300x200?text=2'
                    }
                }
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaJGPj?editors=1010

Comment: Or see docs here - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `thumbs : { autoStart : true, },` option to second argument of `$.fancybox.open`:

```
{
    loop : false,
    thumbs : {
        autoStart : true,
    },
}
```